# Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012:

Tags: java, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I am struggling with below error, while implementing SAML 2.0 in my project.

Details : Server : Tomcat
IDP: ADFS 2.0

Error :

```
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012: An error occurred while processing the request. Contact your administrator for details. ---> 
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClientManager.ProcessRequest(Message request)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest(MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest[T](MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.Issue(HttpSamlMessage httpSamlMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String& newSessionState, String& authenticatingProvider)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.RequestBearerToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.RequestBearerToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(String signOnToken, WSFederationMessage incomingMessage)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SignIn(SecurityToken securityToken)

System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClientManager.ProcessRequest(Message request)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest(MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.ProcessRequest[T](MSISSamlRequest samlRequest)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.MSISSamlProtocolContractClient.Issue(HttpSamlMessage httpSamlMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String& newSessionState, String& authenticatingProvider)
    at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.RequestBearerToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)



The verification of the SAML message signature failed. 
Message issuer: http://XXXXX.XXXX.XXXX.com/adfs/services/trust 
Exception details: 
MSIS1015: Server required signed SAML AuthenticationRequest but no signature present.
```

Here is the my Decoded Authentication Request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Version="2.0" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" IssueInstant="2014-05-20T05:25:51.083Z" IsPassive="false" ID="_abff2b25141987e9da0f33f30b1180d6" ForceAuthn="false" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://inbspg001nfh.as.XXXX.XXXX.com:8443/JavaSamlSP/setcookie.jsp"><samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.com/adfs/services/trust</samlp:Issuer><saml2p:NameIDPolicy xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" AllowCreate="true"/>-<saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Comparison="exact"><saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

If you guys have any idea ,Please help me.. 
Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

This is normally because ADFS expects the Auth Request to be signed and it isn't.

You can either tell the SP to sign the request and leave ADFS as is or tell ADFS not to expect signed requests. (For security go with the former).

Number of ways to fix:

- Set the SP option to sign Auth. Request
- Generate new SP metadata and import.

On the ADFS side:

For the SP:

Set-ADFSClaimsProvider -TargetIdentifier SP-SignedSamlRequestsRequired $False

All of ADFS:

Set-ADFSProperties -SignedSamlRequestsRequired $False

Comment: Thnks .. I just configured ADFS not to expect signed requests,still getting same error.. one more findings : while testing metadata usl from adfs.. its saying : could not establish secure channel for ssl/tls.. any idea.. what is happening .

Answer (score 0):

Got the error `MSIS7012 an error occurred while processing the request. Contact your administrator for details.`

While investigating further the following error showed up:

> Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012: An error
>   occurred while processing the request. Contact your administrator for
>   details. ---> System.ArgumentException: ID4216: The ClaimType 'Namn'
>   must be of format 'namespace'/'name'. Parameter name: claimType

Turned out that claims had been set to Swedish on an English ADFS server. Fixed by renaming `Namn` to `Name`.

[image]